# Recover sqlite_sequence table

Tags: database, sqlite, recovery, file-recovery

is there any way to recover the content from sqlite_sequence table ?

I have SQLite db file which still has the entires if I open the db file with a text editor.
But I open it with grafical SQLite editor, the content is not avalible.

Is there any chance to recover those enties and export them ?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

I have try to export it with SysTools SQLite Database Recoyery Tool, but it doesn't export anything

Comment: What's there to recover? It looks like the table exists and you're able to select its contents.

Comment: it's a bit difficult to explain for me. As you can see the tabe provider doesn't contains the hole (71) provider entries. But as I said  if open it with a text editor, I can see them.

https://prnt.sc/DodJXlQSfzeM

So I just want reover back from the table sqlite_sequence all keys back to the table providers. So I want do the same for all other entries like channels keys etc

Comment: Hmm. What do you think the `sqlite_sequence` table is for?

Comment: I don't know mate. I believe it's something for logs, I am new to the subject but willing to learn.

Comment: Start by reading https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html and https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate but I do not understand the most of the descriptions there, since I am not a DB expert or developer. I just want know whether it's is possible to reconstruct the content (which I can see if I open it with text editor) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the database you're talking about. It is the MPDPLAYER v2.0 database and contains about 3700 channels with active keys.
The database you have cannot be recovered, although it contains all the .mpd and KEY/KID links they are completely mixed up and the structure no longer exists.
If you need the complete database I can help you with that
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mshmW.jpg